# Jinja - render a wrapper div every three iterations

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My profile list looks like this:

```
profile_list = [
    {
        "display_name": "test",
        "description": "Image mit CPU",
        "default": True,
        "kubespawner_override": {
            "image": "fake",
        },
    },
    {
        "display_name": "test",
        "description": "Image mit GPU (small)",
        "kubespawner_override": {
            "image": "fake",
            "extra_resource_guarantees": {"nvidia.com/gpu": "1"},
            "extra_resource_limits": {"nvidia.com/gpu": "1"},
            "node_selector": {"sma-gpu-size": "small"},
        },
    },
....
]
```

I want to wrap a div around three elements and tried the following:

HTML:

```
<div class='form-group' id='kubespawner-profiles-list'> {%- for profile in profile_list %}
    {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 0 %}
    <div class='profilewrapper'>{{ profile.display_name }}
        {% endif %}
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="card-input-element" name="profile" />

            <div class="card-input center">
                <h3 class="panel-heading">{{profile.display_name}}</h3>
                <p class="panel-body">
                    {{profile.description}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </label>
        {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 0 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
</div>
```

I tried to render the starting and ending tag in a seperate if statement, but it will of course only wrap a single element inside the div.

Does anyone have an idea how to wrap THREE elements inside `profilewrapper` instead of a single on every three iterations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 0 %}
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <div class='profilewrapper'>
        {% endif %}
        <label>
            <input type="radio" class="card-input-element" name="profile" />

            <div class="card-input center">
                <h3 class="panel-heading">{{profile.display_name}}</h3>
                <p class="panel-body">
                    {{profile.description}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </label>
        {% if loop.index0 % 3 == 2 or loop.last %}
```

`{% if loop.index0 % 3 == 2 or loop.last %}` is the important part